# 'EmployeeData.Employees' does not contain a constructor that takes 6 argumen

Tags: c#, class

I have problem with this

> Error 1   'EmployeeData.Employees' does not contain a constructor that
>   takes 6 arguments C:\Users\John\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication1\Employee
>   Data.cs   65  26  EmployeeData

(http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=0fbwpthp)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EmployeeData
{
      public class Employees
    {
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private int age;
        private char gender;
        private string PI;
        private string uniEmployeeNum;
       Employees(){}
        Employees(string firstName,
                 string lastName,
                 int age,
                 char gender,
                 string PI,
                 string uniEmployeeNum)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.age = age;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.PI = PI;
            this.uniEmployeeNum = uniEmployeeNum;
        }
        public string FirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        public string LastName()
        {
            return lastName;
        }
        public string PII()
        {
            return PI;
        }
        public string UniEmployeeNum()
        {
            return uniEmployeeNum;
        }
        public int Age()
        {
            return age;
        }
        public char Gender()
        {
            return gender;
        }

    }


    class EmployeeData
    {
        void emp()
        {
            Employees man = new Employees("John", "Johnny", 19, 'm', "68161863181686", "6846684644");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // Employee man = new Employee("John", "Johnny", 19, 'm', "68161863181686", "6846684644");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That means `Employees` class doesn't have a constructor takes 6 arguments.

Comment: as you can see it has

Comment: This was resolved by adding the missing `public` modifier to the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `public` access modifier to your constructors.

Answer (score 0):

In your main function you misspelled "Employees" as "Employee". I would suggest to rename the class to "Employee" as it makes more sense - you create them one at a time.

edit: maybe the single-quotes around gender are unnecessary as well. Try 'm' instead of \'m\'.